# Origin of the term 'HTML5 games'

Tags: html5-history

What made HTML5 games named like that?
I checked out HTML5 in Wikipedia and it tells me that HTML5 provides Canvas. Are HTML5 games named by it?

Answer (score 0):

An HTML5 game allows play directly in a modern web browser without the need for third party plugins. So it has now replaced the discontinued Flash and Unity web players, as the preferred technology used to make web games.

Read more https://www.themotionmonkey.co.uk/definitions/html5-game